# SDL2 on Raspbian/Debian

Tags: linker, raspbian, sdl-2, ada, gnat

I'm trying to link SDL2 on Raspbian Stretch, which is debian-based.

I followed [the instructions](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Linux.2FUnix):

> Debian-based systems (including Ubuntu) can simply do "sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0" to get the library installed system-wide, and all sorts of other useful dependencies, too.

But I have no idea where in the world that installed it and a find . -name **sdl* didn't really help... meanwhile my build command in gnat still tells me it's not finding anything:

```
gnatmake -g main.adb -Isource -I../source/win -I../source -I../SDL2 -gnatwk -gnatwr -gnatwu -D objectFiles -largs -lSDL2 -lSDL2_Mixer -lSDL2_ttf obj1.o obj2.o
(...)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2_Mixer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2_ttf
(...)
```

So I tried building myself according to the instructions below that:

> If you're compiling SDL yourself, here's what we refer to as "the Unix
>   way" of building:
>
> - Get a copy of the source code, either from Mercurial or an official tarball or whatever.
> - Make a separate build directory (SDL will refuse to build in the base of the source tree).
> - Run the configure script to set things up.
> - Run "make" to compile SDL.
> - Run "make install" to install your new SDL build on the system.
>
> This looks something like this:
>
> ```
> hg clone https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL SDL
> cd SDL
> mkdir build
> cd build
> ../configure
> make
> sudo make install
> ```

Everything did what it was supposed to do (or at least nothing said it DIDN'T do what it was supposed to do) but now I still don't know how to link it. I tried copying the libsdl2.so file to the working directory and changing -lSDL2 to -llibsdl2 but no luck. Obviously I need to do the same procedure with the other libraries but I was hoping I could worry about one at a time.

There are further instructions but they seem to apply specifically to C:

> Once you have the library installed, you can use the sdl2-config
>   program to help you compile your own code:
>
> ```
> gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
> ```

And I don't know how to do something similar for Ada.

Problem is, I just have no experience linking in Linux and all the stuff I can find on the internet is so general I can't apply it to my case.

As for why in the world I would want to do this, building this for Raspberry Pi wasn't something I intended from the start of the project, but it has kind of become important for me to be able to do so.

Does anyone know how I can get this working? I can build it with no problem on Windows, so it's really just a matter of getting the library into a state where I can like it for a build on Linux.

Comment: `dpkg -L libsdl2-2.0` should tellyou what it installed. You're likely to need `libsdl2-2.0-dev` too. The same goes for ttf and mixer, these are separate libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and as I expected, it was a total newbie thing.

After copying the .so produced by the SDL build process to the working directory, the mistake I made was to change the linker argument to the full filename of the .so (minus extension):

```
gnatmake -g main.adb -Isource -I../source/win -I../source -I../SDL2 -gnatwk -gnatwr -gnatwu -D objectFiles -largs -llibsdl2 -lSDL2_Mixer -lSDL2_ttf obj1.o obj2.o
```

What I needed to do was actually to leave it how it was:

```
gnatmake -g main.adb -Isource -I../source/win -I../source -I../SDL2 -gnatwk -gnatwr -gnatwu -D objectFiles -largs -lSDL2 -lSDL2_Mixer -lSDL2_ttf obj1.o obj2.o
```

After building SDL_Mixer and SDL_TTF, everything works as expected.

Comment: I’m pretty sure I took out building shared libs. The idea is to build It statically so there are less libs to worry about. Also gnatmake doesn’t allow the use of gpr files, use gprbuild and a gpr file. See the test.gpr.

Answer (score 1):

The Ada compiler can only link against Ada libraries. It cannot link against arbitrary C libraries, like SDL2.

You will need to install something like [sdlada](https://github.com/Lucretia/sdlada).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have specified, though: I'm using SDLAda already, and the project builds on Windows no problem. Let me make that edit.